# Event Listener to know when camera or microphone is executing throw web browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, event-listener, getusermedia

I am building a chrome extension. The task of the extension is to notify user that what resource/service (camera/microphone/location) is on when he visit a site.for https sites chrome browser can remember them when a user allow for a resource. I want to build some code or logic that when a camera or microphone or location (that is allowed before by user) is using by a site i want to notify this.

Ex. one visits a https website.website asked camera permission for capturing profile picture. Later website may take a snapshot or video stream on. this time no prompt will fire as this resource allowed before. I want to notify this use. for a allowed service or resource whenever he uses i want to notify.

I go through chrome developer site, MDN & stack-overflow but nothing or did not pick the right section.Can anyone help me about this? How can i do this?

Comment: Not in the `chrome://` side of the Force, but wouldn't it  be easier to force the settings to be "Always ask" instead of trying to listen to all calls? Otherwise, I guess it won't be that easy, you'll probably have to overwrite all default getters (like MediaDevices.getUserMedia)  and hook a listener on it which should map which device got requested (implies a MediaConstraint parser), and then to hook on the returned stream and all the clone that could get created in order to know when they are released...

Comment: @Kaiido yes that will be best decision. but if you see there is no option to allow once. if you use facebook messenger video call.you have to allow camera & mic (will forever until change) . one may not enough smart to toggle the permission after use.

Comment: Yes but I mean for your extension, it might be easier for it to modify the registry of allowed websites so it is always clear and that the prompt is always shown to the users of your extension. Seems to achieve the same end-goal, in a more robust and probably easier to implement way.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings sounds like what you need no?

Comment: yes i read all there. I already add  feature to modify permission. Your idea is much easier and goal oriented. Still want to cover those situation one may continue to allow. but that case notification of every use can confirm user resource-use is valid.

Comment: @Kaiido can u give me a idea what will be the best way to periodically clean the register